# Maven war artifact with car extension

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, vignette

I am trying to use Maven to generate an artifact for deploying on Vignette Portal. The packaging is exactly the same as a `war` artifact but the file should have `car` extension instead.

Options I've tried and I've not been able to complete.

- Use war plugin and rename the final artifact (keeps adding .war extension)
- Use assembly plugin with zip descriptor (not able to change .zip to .car extension)
- Create a new packaging type as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven) (can't use war plugin for .car extension)

Which would be the easiest 'Maven' way to generate the .car file? Could you give me some guidance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's not possible to rename the main deliverable artifact of a project.

Anyway, in the past, what I've done so far was making maven copy the file with a new name and then "attach" it to the deliverables of a build; by configuring two plugins:

- [maven-ant-run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) to copy
- [maven-build-helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to attach in order to be deployed to my repo along with the main artifact of my project.

  ```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war"
                tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.car" />
            </target>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

And the second:

```
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-instrumented-jar</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
              </goals>
      <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                  <artifact>
                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.car</file>
                    <type>car</type>
                  </artifact>
                </artifacts>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
```

I hope that can help you. At least until you find a better solution.

Comment: For the first example it works for me with the child of `configuration` being `tasks` instead of `target`, maybe because of a newer antrun version?

Comment: @jaime yes, possibly.

Comment: @jaime check the MOJO documentation, looks like `tasks` has been deprecated in favour of `target`. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html