# Maven assembly plug-in - how to produce artifact with custom file extension?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am producing an artifact named `foo.bar.zip` from the following...

**My pom.xml plug-in entry looks like this:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
        <finalName>foo.bar</finalName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**My descriptor file looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>

etc. etc.
```

My question, is how do I produce a file with a custom extension?  E.g. with the name `foo.bar` instead of `foo.bar.zip`.

Comment: You can't. And this use-case is _really_ bizarre. Why would you want to package a ZIP with a `bar` extension? Maven won't let you do that.

Comment: @tunaki, the file extension is expected by a third-party application.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you tell more about your use-case? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @tunkai, it is pretty straight forward -- the third-party application has a proprietary file extension instead of just using requiring .zip.  I'm trying to make what is a really a .zip file build as a .zip file with a custom extension.

Comment: You could try that, never tested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969880/maven-output-jar-with-arbitrary-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) supports just these formats:

> "zip" - Creates a ZIP file format
>
> "tar" - Creates a TAR format
>
> "tar.gz" or "tgz" - Creates a gzip'd TAR format
>
> "tar.bz2" or "tbz2" - Creates a bzip'd TAR format
>
> "jar" - Creates a JAR format
>
> "dir" - Creates an exploded directory format
>
> "war" - Creates a WAR format

You should consider to use [antrun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) in a later goal/phase to rename file extension

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by combining:

1. maven-assembly-plugin
2. copy-rename-maven-plugin
3. build-helper-maven-plugin

The assembly plugin has a configuration option to not attach the file, so I do that:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <attach>false</attach>
</configuration>
```

Then I use the `copy-rename-maven-plugin` to rename the file, produced by `assembly-plugin`, from zip to my custom file type (in my case it is CLI).

After that I use `build-helper-maven-plugin` to attach the artifact with the custom file type.