# What is the exact meaning of "extensions" parameter in maven

Tags: maven, maven-extension

I mean in the extensions parameter in a plugin as follows:

```
<build><plugins><plugin>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <extensions>...</extensions>
    ...
</plugin></plugins></build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html:

> Whether to load Maven extensions (such as packaging and type handlers) from this plugin. For performance reasons, this should only be enabled when necessary. Note: While the type of this field is String for technical reasons, the semantic type is actually Boolean. Default value is false.

This parameter is used when developing a plugin. Further resources (since I have no experience with that):

- [Using Extensions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html)
- [Maven 2.1 Plugin and Extension Loading Design](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Maven+2.1+Plugin+and+Extension+Loading+Design)
- [How do I create a new packaging type for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven)

Comment: My favorite pitfall where this is absolutely necessary is the maven-bundle plugin. Without extensions, you can not define the bundle packaging.