# What does maven do with a bogus packaging type?

Tags: maven

I'm working my way through learning a somewhat complicated maven build.  I've found a module that is using a bogus packaging type, "custom-war" to be specific.  If I execute:

```
mvn -e -X clean install
```

maven complains thus:

```
[DEBUG] Error looking up lifecycle mapping to retrieve optional mojos. Lifecycle 
  ID: clean. Error: Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository:
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMappingcustom-war.
```

However, it appears to go ahead and execute clean:clean, so it must have made some decisions on which goals to map to the lifecycle phases.  Can anyone provide some insight into the decision making of maven in the face of a bogus packaging type?

I think I should add that this custom module appears to be "defining it's own default lifecycle bindings"; I've found a component.xml file that defines goal bindings for phases of the default lifecycle.  In the light of this, the error appears to be complaining that there are no bindings declared for clean, but the format of the component.xml doesn't appear to support that.

Answer (score 1):

The `clean` phase runs through to completion because the goals that are bound to this phase are independent of the packaging.

What should be done in response to the command `mvn install` on the other hand is predicated on the packaging.  Maven encountered an unknown packaging of "custom-war" and so it threw its hands up.

See [correlation of phases to packaging](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) at Maven.

Comment: But it seems to be saying, see `Lifecycle ID: clean`, that it's throwing it's hands up when starting the clean lifecycle.  Am I misreading something here?

Comment: Can you run just `mvn clean` successfully?  It could be that it _appears_ to be failing during clean but really is failing during the initial parsing of the POMs when it encounters an unknown packaging.  IIRC to support new packaging types you need to configure a plugin as providing extensions.  I came across another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven) about working with new packaging.  Maybe that provides some tips.