# extended maven plugin ignores configuration

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

i did a maven plugin that overwrites "maven-jar-plugin" following this doc:
[How do I create a new packaging type for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven)

you can find my plugin here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lucee/lco-plugin/1.0

the source is here:
https://github.com/lucee/lco-maven-plugin

I only change the extension, nothing else, i get the right extension as expected, problem is the configuration is ignored

```
<plugin>      
    <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
    <artifactId>lco-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.01-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- when I use this the configuration works!
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>-->

    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>       
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

any idea what i do wrong?

Comment: Can you show the full pom file?

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/lucee/lco-plugin/1.0/lco-plugin-1.0.pom

Answer (score 1):

You can do further debugging by running your maven build with the -X -e flags activated. This way, you'll see for each running plugin which configuration is loaded.

As the configuration is not loaded, I would suggest it's typically an activation issue that the aforementionned method will allow you to solve.