# Running mvn site doesn't looks for plugins in the url defined in settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I have been trying to generate a site using `mvn -s <path_to_settings.xml> site` command but facing a problem. It says that unable to resolve plugin that is present in a private repository. The URL of the private repository is provided in the `settings.xml` using the `<pluginRepository>` tag.

In my `settings.xml` file I have

```
<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>pluginRepo</id>
     <url>{URL Of the Repository}</url>
      <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Initially I thought it might not be picking up the correct settings file, so I ran the command using `-X` flag and found that it is indeed picking up the correct settings.xml file and correct pluginRepository URL as well.

The relevant output of the debug logs is

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from <global-settings-path>\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from <my-settings-path>\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [
  pluginRepo ({url of private repo}, default, releases+snapshots),
  central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
```

But it gives me error that

```
Failure to find my-plugin:jar:version in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

But when I define the `<pluginRepositories>` in pom.xml the command works fine. i.e. if I add the following in my pom.xml and run the same command `mvn -s <path-to-settings.xml> -X site`

```
<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>pluginRepo1</id>
     <url>{URL Of the Repository}</url>
      <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And in the debug logs, I have

```
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [
  pluginRepo ({url of private repo}, default, releases+snapshots),
  pluginRepo1 ({url of private repo}, default, releases+snapshots),       
  central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
```

My question is : Does `mvn site` command looks for plugins at the URL defined via pluginRepository in settings.xml ?

Comment: is it a custom plugin? did you add that groupId to the pluginGroups in settings.xml as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom plugin. I have added the pluginGroup that in the settings.xml as 
`<pluginGroups><pluginGroup>{my plugin group id}</pluginGroup><pluginGroups>` and using that in the project as  
`<plugin><groupId>{my plugin group id}</groupId>...</plugin>`

Everything is working fine when I run `mvn -s settings.xml clean install` but  I am having problems only with `mvn -s settings.xml site`

Comment: so it is a reporting plugin? or one used for the build? Is the plugin configured as reporting plugin? is it bound to a wrong phase? the site life-cycle differs from the default life-cycle: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference - what error do you get?

Comment: This is not a reporting plugin but packages my code into a zip file. The default phase of the plugin is package. It also defines a new type of packaging my-zip-pacakge using the steps mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven).

Failure to find my-plugin:jar:[unknown versions] in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2