# Lifecycle bindings configuration in Maven plugin

Tags: maven

I have a POM file with a set of bindings, which are supposed to be reused by child projects. It works like spring-boot starter - shares some set of dependencies and plugin bindings among the child projects. I would like to outline the bindings to a separate Maven packaging like it is described in [How do I create a new packaging type for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven), so that child projects are not necessary tied strictly to that starter POM.

However, these bindings have some configuration and it should be outlined together with bindings. In parent POM file I had `<configuration>` section, but in `components.xml` I don't see any analogue. Only the bindings.

How can I configure the bindings in Maven packaging plugin.

Comment: First why do you need that? And what kind of packaging type would you like to have? What is the purpose of this new packaging type?

Comment: Updated the question