# How to get maven to generate an exploded war?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Currently I have a multi-maven project, and my webapp maven project is currently generating a .war file.

How can I have it generate an exploded war?

(It is hard to deploy when it is a single file as it is large, and I am forced to upload the entire file when most of the library files are already on the server after the initial deploy)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352612/how-to-get-maven-to-run-warexploded-but-not-warwar)

Answer (score 2):

You need [`maven-war-plugin:exploded`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look in ./target/$war-name/ -- that should be the complete war, expanded.

Comment: I have that, but it doesn't have the correct file set, wasn't sure why or if it was really an exploded war.