# How do I configure the Maven WAR plugin to execute the "inplace" goal by default?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin, in-place

I’m using Maven 3.2.3 and the Maven War 2.6 plugin.  I would like the “inlace” goal of the Maven WAR plugin to execute by default (without my having to explicitly specify “war:inlace” on the command line).  So I created a profile to include the below

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
            <property>
                    <name>!flag</name>
            </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                                <useCache>true</useCache>
                                <workDirectory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>inplace</goal>
                        </goals>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Using “mvn help:active-profiles”, I have verified this profile is being used when I run “mvn clean install” on my WAR project.  However, the WAR is not assembled in place.  For instance, I get the output

```
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [myproject] in [/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/myproject]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [17460 msecs]
```

Also I notice there are no “classes” or “lib” resources in my src/main/resources/WEB-INF folder.  What do I need to configure differently to get my WAR to be built in-place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Maven to run war:exploded but not war:war](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352612/how-to-get-maven-to-run-warexploded-but-not-warwar) only it's `inplace` instead of `exploded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be classified as a duplicate of [How to get Maven to run war:exploded but not war:war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352612/how-to-get-maven-to-run-warexploded-but-not-warwar) with a small twist. Instead of `exploded` it needs to be `inplace`:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- don't pack the war  -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- optional, depends on your setup -->
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-war</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>war-inplace</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>inplace</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
         ...
    </plugins>
<pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score -1):

The WAR Plugin is responsible for collecting all artifact dependencies, classes and resources of the web application and packaging them into a web application archive.

```
<plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

  <version>3.0.0</version>

</plugin>
```