# How do I build an exploded WAR in a multi-module Maven project and also include sibling JAR files in its WEB-INF/lib directory?

Tags: maven, maven-3, war, maven-war-plugin, exploded

I’m using Maven 3.3.3 with the Maven WAR 2.6 plugin.  I have a multi module project with both JAR and WAR projects within it.  My WAR projects depend on my JAR projects, however, I do not want to package my WAR files, opting instead to keep them in an exploded form.  So I tried running this command

```
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn -B -f /home/jboss/.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/pom.xml -B clean prepare-package war:exploded -DskipTests -T 3
```

Although this keeps my WAR exploded, the JAR projects do not get included in my web application’s target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib directory. Instead what is included are empty directories where my JAR files would have been, for instance

```
.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/child-jar-module-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/
```

How can I keep an exploded WAR, include my JAR files, and do it all from the command line (as opposed to creating a custom profile in my parent pom to do it for me)?

**Edit:** If you think this is a duplicate of another one, notice the part of my question where i point out that empty directories are generated when using the "prepare-package" phase.  I don't want that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Maven to run war:exploded but not war:war](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352612/how-to-get-maven-to-run-warexploded-but-not-warwar)

Comment: The command line option they suggest, using the "prepare-package" Maven lifecycle phase, causes the empty directories to be generated, as is described in my question.

Comment: The comments to command line option suggest that is does not work (well). I tried to reproduce it and `prepare-package war:exploded` does not work for my multi-project. I suspect there is no option to reach what you want, at least in elegant way. BTW, you wrote *creating a custom profile in my parent pom*, you should wrote *creating a custom profile in my pom*, because parent pom may remain unchanged