# Maven unpack war in destination folder

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I use Maven to create WAR of my JEE Application.

Here my pom.xml

```
<finalName>myproject</finalName>
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <outputDirectory>/var/www/myproject/webapp</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>    
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
     <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The generated WAR is copied in output folder defined in pom.xml (/var/www/myproject/webapp) but then i want to unpack it before launch my server (Tomcat).

How can i do?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Comment: why you wanna unpack that? Tomcat can handle the .war files

Comment: Because i'm "hard" development phase and i want to check that war contains all needed files.

Comment: Your `<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>` and `<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>` is a guarantee for a lot of pain and headaches =/. Why not use Maven's convention?

Comment: What do you advice? What is the best practise? i'm new in maven.

Comment: Your source Java files should go under `src/main/java` and the war source should go under `src/main/webapp`. See also https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maven goal [war:exploded](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html)

You can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352612/how-to-get-maven-to-run-warexploded-but-not-warwar#11134940)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to unpack the war, you can use **maven assembly plugin** for that. E.g.:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.10</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>your group id</groupId>
               <artifactId>your artifact id</artifactId>
               <version> your version</version>
               <type>war</type>
               <overWrite>false</overWrite>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
               <destFileName>some name</destFileName>
               <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
               <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
             </artifactItem>
       </artifactItems>
       <includes>**/*.java</includes>
       <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
       <outputDirectory>your location</outputDirectory>
       <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
       <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
```

You can read on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html for more details.